# Data not inserted into table of mySQL (MariaDB)

Tags: python, mysql, database, raspberry-pi, mariadb

I am currently trying to implement a python script that would insert a couple of dummy values into a table of my SQL database (MariaDB). I am using Stretch OS on my Raspberry Pi.

I first successfully created a table in an existing database in MariaDB.

```
MariaDB [testdb]> CREATE table testdbtable (col1 char(1), col2 char(1), col3 char(1));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)
```

Using `show tables;` I can see testdbtable as my created table.

```
+------------------+
| Tables_in_testdb |
+------------------+
| testdbtable      |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Using `show columns from testdbtable;` I get:

```
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| col1  | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| col2  | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| col3  | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I then created a python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import mysql.connector as mariadb 

mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='root', password='', database='testdb')

cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO testdbtable(col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c')");

mariadb_connection.close()
```

This script runs on terminal without any errors. However, when I run MariaDB on terminal, I do not see the dummy values (i.e. a,b,c) being inserted into this table from my script:

```
MariaDB [testdb]> select * from testdbtable;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I appreciate if anyone can give me any advice on what I might have done wrong in my script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you need to commit changes. See this article

https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-connect-python-programs-mariadb

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO testdbtable(col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c')");

mariadb_connection.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks danielarend! `Using mariadb_connection.commit()` solved the problem. I was also initially under the impression that there would be autocommit in mariaDB.

Comment: Oh, that's bad of the Python connector.  It is the reason I hate `autocommit=OFF` -- it defaults to a mode that leads users into this trap.